# Put a JFrame in a jPanel

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I tried to use a Library called "jfreechart" to draw my Pie Chart.The problem here is that i can't integrate the result witsh is in a different Jframe in my window that contains 2 JPanels.So finally " Statistiques " should contains the Pie Chart not in a different window.
[image]

Here is the class of the Pie Chart

```
    public class PieChart extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public PieChart(String applicationTitle, String chartTitle) {
        super(applicationTitle); 
        PieDataset dataset = createDataset();

        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset, chartTitle);

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);


        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));


        setContentPane(chartPanel);

    }


    private  PieDataset createDataset() {
        DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
        result.setValue("Tunis", 29);
        result.setValue("Ariana", 20);
        result.setValue("Sousse", 51);
        return result;

    }


    private JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset, String title) {

  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(title,dataset,true,true,false);

        PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setStartAngle(290);
        plot.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);
        plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
        return chart;

    }
}
```

Comment: Put a JFrame in a jPanel, are you sure ?

Comment: 1) PieChart extends JFrame and 2) the view in the right of the image is a 2 Jpanels

Comment: Ask the PieChart class for a copy of the ChartPanel to add to your other Container.

Comment: I was always told that the JPanel goes int he JFrame because the JFrame is the a heavy weight component. Actual you do not even have to put the JPanel in the JFrame but I think you will find that it is convent to have at least one Panel in the JFrame in case you want to do some graphics programming. The paintComponent() will let you do that. Onto FreeChart i have used that some for a project a while back but my bose had the documentation and it was much easier than. I think you need the docuementation to make it easy going with this third party vendor software. But JFreeCharts are look nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a `JFrame` in a `JPanel` is afaik not possible, but you can put the pie chart in a `JPanel`.

```
PieDataset dataset = createDataset();

JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset, chartTitle);

ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));

yourPanel.add(chartPanel);     // this line is new
```

Comment: You would have to have the JFreeChart .jar installed in eclipse. It was already installed on the computer that I was using it on a while back. Can you put up a complete working sample of a small pie chart. That would be unbelievable nice and very helpful. thank you

Comment: I have never used `JFreeChart`. But I think you can use it like any other library out there. Add the jar-file to the build path of the project and simply use it :) Btw. there is a nice [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JFreeChart/article.html) out there using `JFreeChart`

Comment: Correct; More examples are cited in `learn more…` for [tag:jfreechart].